# What do most people use to work with SSIS packages since VS2015 UI is buggy?

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio-2015

I don't think I can post bugs on Microsoft connect. I'm trying to use SSDT on VS community edition. And the UI is terribly buggy. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

The Enumerator properties manager is just painful. I can drag it down a tiny bit but can still barely read one line at a time.

[image]

And this image is another example. What tools do most people use to develop SSIS in? I can't believe that it's the same ones I'm using...

I'm using a surface pro 4 that is up-to-date as far as I know

Comment: I don't think most people have that issue. Are you sure it's not something with your font size defaults?

Comment: I dont have that issue. What is the resolution of your monitor?

Comment: I'm not using an external monitor - just the surface display. The resolution is 2736 x 1824 pixels (default). Font size is set to 200% (recommended), presumably because of the high resolution compared to most monitors

Comment: even when setting the surface to display font at 100% i still have that issue. in addition to everything being tiiiiiiiny. so it wouldn't be a useful solution anyway

Comment: Windows 10 DPI issues?... I dont have that going on because my monitors are £120 22"

Comment: I've always encountered that issue with the for each file enumerator too. Another nice bug is where suddenly the layout goes wrong and everything appears at the bottom of the canvas with acres of space above.

Comment: And I've noticed this issue when looking at packages on other Dev's machines too so unlikely we are all unknowingly using exotic resolutions.

Comment: When opening the same package via RDP (Server 2012), I see the same problem. However when someone else opens the package via RDP they see it as it's supposed to be displayed. So I think it's a display problem specifically on a surface pro 4, and possibly other pcs as @MartinSmith mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post on connect with any version and I would encourage you to.

These issues aside I think the only sane way to work with ssis is to use biml to write your packages and compile that into ssis.

This means you don't need to keep going into the properties of each task ad-infinitum- if you want to see how a task is configured you scroll down in the biml and look.

It is a bit more work upfront but as soon as you need to make a change or look at an old package it will pay off dividends.

There are other advantages like easy source code management, comparing biml files for changes is much easier than the raw ssis xml that changes id's every time you press "build".

Forget writing ssis packages using the ide and use it to debug packages when you really really need to .

Just to add on that when you experience the pain of being in the script editor ide and needing to close it down, close down th script properties, go into the data flow and look at the properties of a destination task and then go into the mappings tab to then close it all back to go back to the script task you realise that native ssis development is horrible!

Comment: No man, look at the resolution he pointed out... I'm almost 100% positive its a win10/dpi issue... and word on the street is [microsoft its not fussed](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/83964/microsoft-may-never-fix-high-dpi-issues-windows-10)

Comment: Hey man, the point is that the whole ide for ssis is not conductive to effective use, so use biml and who cares about the ide's quirks!

Comment: ha! ok man... just saying...

Comment: Well we can revisit this answer in a few months when SSDT is released for VS 2017 and Varigence has not yet to release any new version of BimlExpress. Biml has it's problems in some areas, one big one is their documentation is lacking on how to do the advanced items. If you are building out basic packages, then yes it is absolutely the way to go. If you are using Mist however, kudos, but I've never come across anyone willing to pay that much.

Comment: I'd just like to add that almost everytime i touch a UI control VS2015 shell freezed...

Comment: well it's a year later and still no ssdt for VS2017 @ShawnMelton! who'd have thought.

Comment: @ZachSmith yes there is SSDT for VS 2017.

Comment: @ZachSmith This was released months ago as more or less GA but has been available since last year: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @ShawnMelton - thanks! and this gives the ability to edit SSIS packages in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @ZachSmith yes, SSDT 2017 supports all supported versions of SQL Server for SSIS, believe for SSRS and SSAS now as well but not 100% sure on the last two.